# Connect Salesforce Marketing Cloud to Looker Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, integration

I´m trying to connect Salesforce Marketing Cloud to Looker Studio in order to analyze different data and campaign. This data is stored in a Data Extension.

How is this possible? Anyone have done?

I´m trying through Skyvia so connected the API and small Data Extensions are received in Looker Studio but big ones not. ¿Is this possible?

Thank you in advance, any information regarding this is well received.

Comment: Did you try going through Google Cloud Storage? MC supports adding these as a file location in setup.

Comment: @LukasLunow Thanks Lukas!! I made the configuration through file location in setup but having and error when executing the automation in the file transfer:

"File not found matching the pattern GCP://bucket-quickstart_shaped-strata-xxxxx/Google Cloud Storage"

¿Do you know how to fix this? ¿Is correctly done the file transfer in the automation?

I currently use file transfer with the FTP to export data.

Thanks for all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a number of ways, but looking into the capabilities of Automation Studio, and on GCS being a Google product, similar to Looker, you can do this via Google Cloud Storage. Here is how:

1. Create GCS as File Location in MC:
   [image]

[Read here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_openstack_platform/13/html/google_cloud_backup_guide/creds) how you obtain a credentials file.

2. Create data extension extract:
   [image]
3. Create File Transfer activity:
   [image]

(remember to have consistent naming convention between extract and file transfer)

4. Run the automation and see the file arrive in your Google Cloud Storage:
   [image]
5. Add your Google Cloud Storage as Data Source in Looker Studio. Here is a guide on [how-to](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7511998).

Comment: Thanks Lukas!!! You are the best. You helped me a lot, appreciate.

For other people, GCS needs UTF-8 data so is mandatory transform data through the automation from UTF-16 to UTF-8. It's possible through Data extract/ convert file.